# Select all items from a table and check if there is corresponding items in another table

Tags: mysql, join

i'm trying to workout this problem : 
I got a table A of default value and a table B of custom value for certain entities. 
For example :
I got my first table of default value here

[image]

And i want to select all of them , but i also want the one from the value table B [image]

I can do that for every entry with a simple join, the problem is that i want only the value of the entity #45, So in the end it would look something like that :
[image]

If any ones has any idea on how to do this or at least some references it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
SELECT t1.*
 ,t2.value
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
TableB t2 
ON t1.id = t2.fk_id_setting
And t2.fk_id_entities=45
```